# Android - validating self-signed certificates in addition to normal SSL certificates

Tags: java, android, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an Android application that calls web services over SSL. In production we will have normal SSL certificates that are signed by a trusted CA. However, we need to be able to support self-signed certificates (signed by our own CA).

I have successfully implemented the suggested solution of accepting self-signed certificates but this will not work due to the risk of man in the middle attacks. I then created a trustmanager that validates that the certificate chain was in fact signed by our CA.

The problem is I have to bypass the normal SSL validation - the application will now only speak to a server that has one of our self-signed certificates installed.

I am a bit lost, I've googled extensively but can't find anything. I was hoping to find a way of programmatically adding our CA to the trust store on the device as this would be the least intrusive way of dealing with the issue.

What I want to achieve:
1. Full standard support for normal SSL certificates.
2. Additional support for self-signed certificates signed by our own CA.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted any code, so I can't be sure what you actually did.  However, I'll assume that you're setting up a `SSLContext` using only your custom `X509TrustManager` subclass.  That's fine, but what you can do is have your custom trust manager implementation *also* chain to the built-in trust managers.  You can do this while setting up your trust manager; something like this should work:

```
private List<X509TrustManager> trustManagers = new ArrayList<X509TrustManager>();

public MyCustomTrustManager() {
    TrustManagerFactory tmFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmFactory.init((KeyStore)null);

    for (TrustManager tm : tmFactory.getTrustManagers()) {
        if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager)
            trustManagers.add((X509TrustManager)tm);
    }
}
```

So now your custom trust manager has a list of all the built-in trust managers.  In your override of `checkServerTrusted()`, you'll want to loop through the built-in trust managers and check each one by calling `checkServerTrusted()` on each one in turn.  If none of them trust the certificate, you can apply your own cert checking.  If that passes, you can return normally.  If not, just throw a `CertificateException` as you'd otherwise do.

EDIT:  Adding the below about doing things like host name verification.

You can also verify that the hostname in the certificate matches what you expect it to be.  You'll want to pass in the valid hostname in your constructor for your custom trust manager and stash it in the class.  Your `checkServerTrusted()` method will get passed an array of `X509Certificate`.  Many "chains" will consist of just a single cert, but others will have several, depending on how the cA signed your cert.  Either way, the first cert in the array should be "your" cert that you want to compare against.

After you check for basic cert validity using the trust managers, you'll then want to do something like this:

```
Principal subjectDN = chain[0].getSubjectDN();
String subjectCN = parseDN(subjectDN.getName(), "CN");
if (this.allowedCN.equals(subjectCN)) {
    // certificate is good
}
```

The implementation of `parseDN()` is left up to you.  `subjectDN.getName()` will return a comma-separated list of key-value pairs (separated by `=`), something like `C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=www.google.com`.  You want the CN ("Common Name") value for your hostname comparison.  Note that if you have a wildcard cert, it'll be listed as something like `*.example.com`, so you'll need to do more than a simple equals match in that case.

Comment: You can take a look to the http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2012/05/android-ssl-self-signed-certificate.html, maybe will help you.

Comment: @ziziana that's not useful. the example on that page allows any certificate, whether valid, invalid, revoked, expired, self-signed, whatever.

Comment: kelnos, thanks. I didn't post code because the question is not related to accepting self-signed certs, etc. Your suggestion is good, however it does not address the other things that get checked (like host name verification, etc).

Comment: @Will777 you haven't actually asked anything else in your question about host name verification, but I'll update my answer to reflect that as well.

Comment: @kelnos - noted. However, this is what I meant with "Full standard support for normal SSL certificates" - standard validation includes host name verification. Thank you for all your assistance

Comment: @Will777 not sure what you mean.  My solution does that just fine.  Chaining to the built-in trust managers will do all the standard verification steps as if you weren't implementing your own.

Comment: @kelnos, chaining trust managers work great for establishing trust of the certificate chain. My comment was in relation to the fact that you still need to verify the host name as this is part of the normal procedure. Most people, using self-signed certificates, will include a naive host name verifier that always returns true. I was hoping to find a method to use the default mechanism for host name verification as well - not rolling out my own.

Comment: @Will777 it's not clear to me what you want, then.  if you just want the ability to make sure that the hostname on the cert matches the hostname of the site being accessed, you don't need to do anything else.  if you only want to allow self-signed certs for particular hostnames overall, then you'll have to roll your own solution... which isn't a big deal since it's < 10 lines of code.

Comment: @kelnos Thank you for your answer, it pointed me in the right direction. For some reason, it took me quite some time to find something beyond "accept everything" or "accept only yours".

Comment: @Will777 Not sure if I got your point right, but while validating the hostname should be done for regular certificates (and will be done by such an implementation), in my eyes, it does not make much sense for one's own certificate. The question is always: What do you want to be protected against? Anyone else can self-sign a certificate with your hostname, too... I'd say the hostname is not the right place to check whether this is "your" self-signed certificate,

Comment: @ClassStacker My point was I wanted a mechanism to extend the normal verification procedure to also validate my own certificate in addition to other certificates - of this mechanism, host name verification is also a part but by no means the most important. For self-signed certs you could check that the certificate was signed by your own CA which is much safer. I wanted one solution that would do the normal SSL check but also accept my own certs, safely.

Comment: @Will777 I absolutely agree it's best to extend the X509 Trust Managers on a per-app basis for checking a specific self-signed certificate while leaving the regular mechanism intact. But I have come to the conclusion that when I check my own certificate, "all" I do is checking its integrity (signature against body) (does anybody else do that, didn't find any code snippets on the Web) and a secure hash of the RSA public key (modulus and pub exp). Everything else appears pretty meaningless to me, because this way, I have checked that this certificate has been created with "my" private RSA key.

Comment: @ClassStacker I agree, that should be more than sufficient. I've found examples of people verifying that the cert chain was signed by the custom CA. Thanks for the comments

Comment: @ClassStacker I've actually had to do the hostname verification before. I don't want to depend on having my own CA, but will trust the system's trusted CAs.  So I have a cert signed by a system-trusted CA, but I really only want to accept a cert with my hostname.  It's maybe a little less secure than having one's own CA, as it relies on the public CAs to not do bad things (like issue some random person a cert using my hostname).  But it also means I don't have to go to the effort to secure and back up my own CA.

Comment: @kelnos Absolutely. With a "real" certificate, hostname checking is essential. (Does the standard X509 Trust Manager implementation do it? I hope so?)

Comment: @ClassStacker The standard manager makes sure the requested hostname matches what's on the certificate, but if you want to restrict that further to a short list of your own, you need to do something like I described in this answer.

Comment: Hi @kelnos. I am trying to add my server's SelfSigned certificate into  TrustManager,  but getting an exception at "checkServerTrusted()" as you have mentioned above, but you have also mentioned that **If none of them trust the certificate, you can apply your own cert checking.**, can you please guide me how can i do that?

Comment: @Ankit sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: hi @kelnos thanks for your reply, i completed that part, actually there was a problem in server self-signed certificate. They were also implementing first time. I would like to suggest others if you find any problem like me, first of all please make sure server side certificate is properly created and configured at their end and then look for some solution.

Comment: @will777 How to validate a certificate using trust manager. I have to validate a signed certificate using ca certificate.

Comment: I have created TrustManagerFactory but what to do with that TrustManagerFactory. it is not giving any method something like validate(cert, ca_cert); @Will777

Comment: @kelnos Can you help me to split up certification handling into Host, Peer, Both & None categories: please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47323985/2579281