# Adding custom CA to android

Tags: java, android, ssl, ca

How can I add an own CA Certificat in android? It seems only possible by using the global key manager. But I don't want users to import this key first.

It doesn't have to be installed globaly, only for my application.

I was also looking throu the android SSL Classes but I'm not so familiar with SSL in programming that I'm not sure what Class migth help me.

This solved my question:
[Android - validating self-signed certificates in addition to normal SSL certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152198/android-validating-self-signed-certificates-in-addition-to-normal-ssl-certific)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for what's usally called `FakeSocketFactory`. This enables usage of SSL cerificates without verifying them (with `CA` or other certification entity).

You may addapt the class `NaiveTrustManager` in code bellow to check against your own CA certificate.

You can find a code example in [Fake Socket Factory](http://www.example8.com/category/view/id/15663)

Regards.

Comment: using own CA for verification does not mean no CA verification at all, so your assumption is quite false.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com You are quite right. I misunderstood the objective. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Luis This looks very promising. Thak you. I also found another question on stackoverflow that seems to cover the same. But your solution looks a bit nicer.